# Field Error keys changing with Xwork upgrade to 2.0.6

Tags: java, struts2, dependencies, upgrade, xwork

I've upgraded Xwork from 2.0.4 to 2.0.6 (struts version is 2.0.11.1).  The field validation is working correctly, however the keys for the errors are not.  For example, I have a required field called profile.name.firstName.  The field error key is now coming up as profile.profile.name.firstName.  The first value in the dot-notation is always repeated when the error is coming from Xwork validation.

Any ideas of what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a change in the body of **getFullFieldName** method of class **VisitorFieldValidator**:

```
diff -rNau xwork-2.0.4-sources/ xwork-2.0.6-sources/
```

Output:

```
         public String getFullFieldName(String fieldName) {
+            if (parent instanceof AppendingValidatorContext) {
+                return parent.getFullFieldName("") + field + "." + fieldName;
+            }
         return field + "." + fieldName;
     }
```

Also try to investigate compatibility [test results](http://upstream-tracker.org/java/versions/xwork.html). It seems to be a lot of dangerous changes in the API between 2.0.4 and 2.0.6 (several removed methods). The developers **don't follow** versioning conventions and I suppose the behavior may change regularly. You cannot update even minor versions without a breakage.